# Over ZF, does CUCSCS imply that every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite? (C: Countable, etc.)

Tags: set-theory, infinity, axiom-of-choice

We add

Axiom CUCSCS: The countable union of countable sets is a countable set.

to ZF.

Is every infinite set now Dedekind-infinite?

My work:

When I look at CUCSCS I see no natural path of building an injection of $\mathbb N$ into a given infinite set (no AOC here).

The answer is either yes, no, or not solved (or unsolvable?!?).

Comment: What _is_ your pay grade, though? Is this homework?

Comment: What does infinite mean here? In my understanding it means that it contains a copy of $\mathbb N$. But that would imply, with no extra assumptions, that any infinite set is Dedekind infinite (since $\mathbb N$ is and supersets of Dedekind infinite sets are Dedekind infinite).

Comment: @Stefan The standard definition of infinite is that it is not finite. That is, it is not in bijection with any finite ordinal. We can easily conclude from this (by induction) that if $A$ is infinite, then $A$ has more than $n$ elements for any $n\in\omega$.

Comment: I up-voted @AndrésE.Caicedo comment - that is the definition of infinite.

Comment: @Stefan On the contrary, the axiom eliminates a lot of potential infinite Dedekind finite sets. I don't understand your claim at all. For instance, it is consistent with ZF that there are countable unions of sets of size 2 that are infinite and Dedekind finite.

Comment: I've upvoted - I'm sure the answer's no, but unless I'm missing something it seems hard.

Comment: @Noah: If only there was a reference at hand... oh wait. I'll go get it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila See, I *would* travel all the six hundred feet or so to my own copy, but since there's a cat on my lap I'm sure you'd get there faster, so why bother? :P

Comment: @Noah: I would have already gotten there. But I was getting off a bus, and had to take a break. And now I'm wasting time writing these comments... :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In Cohen's first model there is a Dedekind finite set of reals, but countable unions of countable sets are countable in that model.

The proof is difficult, indeed, and requires intimate understanding of the construction of the Cohen model.

The idea, in a nutshell, is that if $A$ is a countable family of countable sets, this fact is forced by a condition, so it is witnessed by a finite set of our generic reals. From that we can prove that there is a uniform enumeration of all the sets in the family with the same support. So all the sets are uniformly counted, and therefore their union is countable.

The proof, in fact, shows that a well-ordered union of well-ordered sets is well-ordered. Which is far stronger than just the countable counterpart.

(See also the Howard–Rubin book **Consequences of the Axiom of Choice**, Forms 9 and 31 are the relevant ones, Cohen's model is aptly denoted by $\mathcal M1$.)